# sequelize query to get different columns in for different row depending on a column value

Tags: node.js, plsql, sequelize.js

I have a following schema

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Photo = sequelize.define(
    "Photo",
    {
      photoURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      blurPhotoURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      userId: { //userId of user who has uploaded the photo
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
      },
      isPublic: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        default: false
      }
    }
    {}
  );
}
```

I have one more schema `SubscriberInfo`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const SubscriberInfo = sequelize.define(
    "SubscriberInfo",
    {
      userId: { // subscriber userId
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
      },
      modelId: { //subscribed userId
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

So think like an Instagram profile where a user gets the ability to hide a photos and only his follower can see the photo and reset of the user will see blur version of the same photo.

I have managed to save blur photo and original photo in my db and `isPublic` is the column which tell if a photo is private or not.

On my UI(profile section) i want to display photos and blur photos depending on the user who is viewing the persons profile.

Can I achieve this in one query where in my returned JSON I get `blurPhotoURL` or `photoURL` depending who the user is and if the photo is `isPublic` or not.

Thank you in adv!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
select 
  case when CUR_VIEWER_USER in  -- check if current user is SubscriberInfo 
(select modelId SubscriberInfo SI 
    where p.userId = si.userId) 
  then photoURL 
  else  blurPhotoURL as photo_for_user 
from Photo P
 where isPublic = true 
 or (isPublic = false and userId  = CUR_VIEWER_USER) -- if curUser is owner show his unpublished photos
```

from that query you can get basic idea, how to change it to your fit. Im not sure how to insert current_user into query but still you a have starting point.

Comment: This is a sql query how can do it using sequelize.